# Arrays in numerical order (without importing array.sort() option)

Tags: java, arrays, numerical

I would like to sort my two arrays in numerical order. So if I input something like: `96 2 1 42 49 5`, it'll give me an output of: `1 2 42 49 96`.

How would you do this using a for-loop? I'm trying to implement a basic for-loop to get my numbers to ascend numerically.

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Input up to '10' numbers for current array: ");

    int[] array1 = new int[10];
    int i;
    int k;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Input a number for " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        if (input == -9000) {
            break;
        } else {
            array1[i] = input;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\n" + "Array 1: ");

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

        System.out.println((j + 1) + ": " + array1[j]);
    }

    int[] array2 = new int[i];

    System.out.println("\n" + "Array 2: ");

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        array2[j] = array1[j];

        System.out.println((j + 1) + ": " + array2[j]);
    }
    scan.close();

  }
}
```

Comment: Read about [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)...

Comment: You will need two nested loops for a simple [bubble-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Bubble Sort**. You will be required to use 2 for loops.

**Complexity** of bubble sort is `O(n2)`

```
package com.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n, c, d, swap;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input number of integers to sort");
        n = in.nextInt();

        int array[] = new int[n];

        System.out.println("Enter " + n + " integers");

        for (c = 0 ; c < n ; c++)
            array[c] = in.nextInt();

        for (c = 0 ; c < (n - 1) ; c++) {
            for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1 ; d++) {
                if (array[d] > array[d + 1]) /* For descending order use < */
                {
                    swap = array[d];
                    array[d] = array[d + 1];
                    array[d + 1] = swap;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Sorted list of numbers");

        for (c = 0 ; c < n ; c++)
            System.out.println(array[c]);
    }
}
```

**output**

```
Input number of integers to sort
5
Enter 5 integers
96
2
1
42
49
Sorted list of numbers
1
2
42
49
96
```

Comment: I still don't get how this works. Can you show me how I can implement the bubble sort with my code?

Answer (score -1):

There are numerous [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) that can address this task. Each algorithm makes a trade-offs between speed and complexity. The simplest sorting algorithm is the [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). Bubble sort is inefficient, but totally reasonable to use if you are dealing with small arrays.